# Access rows of dataframe based on a column of lists. If a unique string is inside the list, the row will be be viewed

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, apply

This is difficult to explain, so I haven't been able to google my problem.

I have a dataframe. A column of that dataframe contains lists. Each row has a list of strings. The lists are of various size. Some rows don't have a list, but a NaN value.

I want to be able to view rows of the dataframe that contain an arbitrary string in their list. So if I want to find all rows that have a list that contains "arbitrary_string" as an element of the list, those rows will be selected.

[Here is an image indicating an example dataframe.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsRYL.png)

I want to use the term "corndog" to return a view of row 1 and 2. The location in the list of the string does not matter. My associates suggested I try to use lambdas and apply and a special function together. Their examples haven't worked for me.

They propose:

```
def find_id(inpList:list,inpstr):  
    print(inpList)
    for x in inpList:
        if inpstr in x:
            return(1)
    return(0)

Df[list_of_strings].apply(lambda x: find_id(x, cust string))
```

I'm not really sure what I'm doing. I don't understand how these things could be pieced together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, I think you can use this:

Original df:

```
+----+-----------+--------------+----------------------------+
|    | some_int  | some_string  |      List_of_strings       |
+----+-----------+--------------+----------------------------+
| 0  |       84  | something    | [‘cat’,’dog’,’corndog’]    |
| 1  |       74  | etc          | [‘qwetry’,’celphone’]      |
| 2  |       64  | etc          | [‘dog’,corndog’]           |
| 3  |       89  | etc          | [‘etc’,’catfish’,’purple’] |
+----+-----------+--------------+----------------------------+
```

```
df[df['List_of_strings'].str.contains('corndog')]
```

Output:

```
    some_int    some_string  List_of_strings
0   84          something   [‘cat’,’dog’,’corndog’]
2   64              etc     [‘dog’,corndog’]
```

**EDIT**
considering column value are of list type and not string you can use following:

```
df[df['List_of_strings'].apply(lambda x: 'corndog' in x)]
```

Comment: I think this assumes that the List_of_strings column is a string itself:
i.e. '["cat", "dog", "corndog"]' rather than ["cat","dog","corndog"]
I wasn't able to get this to work.

I did get it to work by just joining the list into a string. So I'm set, thank you! However I don't think the original question is answered, so I'll leave it open.

Comment: updated my answer, please check if it fulfills your requirement.